# CSS não funciona em páginas geradas com ErrorDocument

Tags: html, css, htaccess

Estou com um problema quando vou personalizar ERRO 404.
Coloquei o seguinte código no arquivo .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /erro404.html
```

E criei uma página personalizada error404.html. A página é onpage, não tem link para outras páginas.

Quando digito por ex. meusite/contato cai no erro404.html, até aí tudo bem. Mas quando coloco por ex. meusite/contato/ (barra) ele não puxa o css (fica todo desconfigurado). O que pode ser?

Comment: Tenta colocar no seu HTML dentro do head a seguinte tag: <base href="/" target="_blank">

Comment: Ainda continua Felipe :(

Comment: "...Mas quando coloco por ex. meusite/contato/ (barra) ele não puxa o css (fica todo desconfigurado)..." Mas o que acontece? Mostrar a pagina 404 mas sem o css?

Comment: Isso. Se eu colocar / no final de qq palavra, abre a página sem o css :/

Comment: Então, colocou a tag que enviei acima na página erro404.html?

Comment: Tinha colocado no index rs Agora coloquei na página erro404, apareceu a imagem que eu tinha colocado, mas os textos ainda continua desconfigurado.

Comment: na página erro404.html vc tem o link para o CSS, pode copiar e colar aqui?

Comment: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/bootstrap.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">`

Comment: Tente assim: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/responsive.css">

Comment: Maravilha @FilipeMoraes !! Agora Funcionou \o/ Obrigado =D

Comment: Maravilha! Vou postar como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere os links do seu css para apontar para raiz do servidor, por exemplo, se estiver assim:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Altere e coloque assim:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Veja que há uma diferença no `href`, tem uma barra no inicio, isso indica que o seu ficheiro css está dentro da pasta css que está na raiz do servidor.

Comment: PERFEITO! Funcionou corretamente ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adicione na sua página erro404.html o seguinte código html:

Se as pastas css, js e images estiverem na raiz:

```
<base href="/">
```

Ou pode tentar isto:

```
<base href="http://www.examplo.com/">
```

Esta tag aponta para que os *resources* carreguem como se estivessem na página especificada no `<base>`.

<sub>Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base</sub>

Comment: Guilherme, como ele aceitou a sua resposta, sugiro acrescentar o que escrevi abaixo como resposta, está faltando informação. Veja os comentários que estão na pergunta. Digo isso porque a reposta pode ajudar outros se estiver mais completa. Abraço.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Desculpe que informação, só vejo sobre o `<link>`, a tag base é pra funcionar como se fosse na página especificada. São métodos alternativos.